# How to disable offline OAuth2 access from Google Drive SDK initiated connections?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm integrating our web app with Google Drive, and got stuck on configuring the conections initiated by the Google Drive UI.

We allow users to open and create files from Drive, but every time OAuth2 session is initiated from the Drive page, it asks for access to files (looks like drive.file scope, which is already given), and also to "Perform these operations when I'm not using the application". I assume the re-authentication is requested because of the offline access, which we never request and don't need. I'd rather not ask users for this if not necessary.

I could not find a way to disable this from the Google API Console. Is there a way to configure the OAuth2 url for sessions initiated from Google Drive UI and set the access_type?

Or, if that is not the issue, what causes the "Perform these operations when I'm not using the application" and constant re-authorisation when files are opened?

if it helps with troubleshooting, the APP id is 399581875395

Comment: Show us your OAuth code.

Comment: we don't have any, the connections are not initiated by us but by google drive. The URL in the middle of the authentication process, when re-authorisation is requested, is `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file&client_id=399581875395.apps.googleusercontent.com&response_type=code&user_id=XXXX&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=http://www.mindmup.com/gd&state=XXXX`

Comment: I am having an identical issue still. Did you find a resolution?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563728/what-causes-a-google-drive-application-to-request-permission-to-perform-these-o  ?

Comment: @Quango no. That answer about OAuth2 in general. in this question Google drive does the first step of the OAuth2 flow and sets offline=true

Answer (score 0):

Answered in [Opening file from google drive always requests offline access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557329/opening-file-from-google-drive-always-requests-offline-access)

Looks like I found a solution for this.
This message will keep appearing if you don't do step2 of the OAuth2 flow with the same client_id and client_secret.

```
@app.route('/open')
def drive_open_file():
    code = request.args.get('code')
    if code:
        credentials = credentials_from_code("client", "secret",
                               "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
                               code,
                               redirect_uri="<WEBSITE>/open")
```